# wait and wait on time differences?

Tags: java, multithreading, wait

I faced this question in one of the Interview.

What is the difference between wait and wait on time in threads?

I know wait method Causes the current thread to wait until either another thread invokes the notify() method or the notifyAll() method for this object, or a specified amount of time has elapsed. But I am not sure what is wait on time he is asking.

Can any one please explain what is wait on time means?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: same thing whatever you told. overloaded version of wait method.

Comment: I've never heard of "wait on time" either.  If somebody asked me that question in a job interview, I would not have hesitated to ask what they were talking about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They probably mean `Object.wait(long timeout)` vs `Object.wait()`, read `java.lang.Object` API for details

Comment: Would you please give a word here ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28665037/concurrency-advanced-python-and-interaction-with-different-objects

Comment: @ Evgeniy Thanks for your answer and valuable time .

Answer (score 3):

`void wait();`

Enter a monitor's wait set until notified by
another thread.

`void wait(long timeout);`

Enter a monitor's wait set until notified by
another thread or timeout milliseconds elapses.

`void wait(long timeout, int nanos);`

Enter a monitor's wait set until notified by
another thread or timeout milliseconds plus
nanos nanoseconds elapses

Comment: Thanks for your answer and valuable time

Answer (score 0):

[From Java Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait(long))

> public final void wait(long timeout)
>                   throws InterruptedException

Causes the current thread to wait until either another thread invokes the notify() method or the notifyAll() method for this object, or a specified amount of time has elapsed.

Comment: @ rai  Thanks for your answer and valuable time.